# Serious Bug with LongListSelector with Itemtemplate or IValueConverter

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, itemtemplate, longlistselector

I'm about to pull my hair off, but before I do that I'll try asking you guys for help... perhaps someone had the same problem and can help me out.

So here is the deal. I have a LongListSelector named SourceZoneSelect defined as such:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="SourceZoneSelect" Grid.Row="2" 
                LayoutMode="Grid" 
                GridCellSize="160,160"
                BorderThickness="0"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="White"
                Width="480" Foreground="Black" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateContentZone}"
                Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorStyleContentZone}"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="-2,0,0,0"/>
```

The ItemTemplate is a DataTemplateSelector as such:

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateContentZone">
                    <local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        ...
                        <local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector.PhotoWebSelect>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="158" Width="158">
                                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleStyle}" Width="158" Height="158" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Click="Button_SourceZone_Select_Click">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="158">
                                            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource StayfilmThirdColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="158" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158"/>
                                            <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="158" Height="158" Source="{Binding Thumb}" Tag="{Binding ImgUrl}"/>
                                            <Grid x:Name="GridSelected" Tag="{Binding idMedia}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Background="#FF0E9B00" Visibility="{Binding selected, Converter={StaticResource PhotoSelectedConverter}}">
                                                <Path Data="F1M0.555,6.585L0.089,6.077C-0.036,5.942,-0.029,5.73,0.107,5.605L1.464,4.344C1.525,4.287 1.606,4.255 1.689,4.255 1.785,4.255 1.871,4.293 1.935,4.361L5.661,8.373 12.07,0.126C12.134,0.047 12.23,0 12.334,0 12.41,0 12.481,0.024 12.54,0.07L14.003,1.206C14.073,1.26 14.117,1.339 14.128,1.429 14.141,1.518 14.116,1.606 14.061,1.674L5.826,12.263z" Fill="White" Margin="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector.PhotoWebSelect>
                        <local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector.VideoSelect>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="158" Width="158">
                                <Button BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleStyle}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Click="Button_SourceZone_Select_Click">
                                    <Grid Height="158" Width="158">
                                        <Image x:Name="videoThumb" Stretch="Fill" Width="158" Height="158" Source="{Binding VideoThumbUrl}"/>
                                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Source="/Assets/Dark/feature.video.png"/>
                                        <Grid x:Name="GridSelected" Tag="{Binding idMedia}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Background="#FF0E9B00" Visibility="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource VideoSelectedConverter}}">
                                            <Path Data="F1M0.555,6.585L0.089,6.077C-0.036,5.942,-0.029,5.73,0.107,5.605L1.464,4.344C1.525,4.287 1.606,4.255 1.689,4.255 1.785,4.255 1.871,4.293 1.935,4.361L5.661,8.373 12.07,0.126C12.134,0.047 12.23,0 12.334,0 12.41,0 12.481,0.024 12.54,0.07L14.003,1.206C14.073,1.26 14.117,1.339 14.128,1.429 14.141,1.518 14.116,1.606 14.061,1.674L5.826,12.263z" Fill="White" Margin="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector.VideoSelect>
...
</local:ContentZoneTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And also 2 value converters:

```
in .xaml file

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:PhotoSelectedConverter x:Name="PhotoSelectedConverter"/>
        <local:VideoSelectedConverter x:Name="VideoSelectedConverter"/>


in .cs file

    public class PhotoSelectedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            bool selected = (bool)value;
            if (!selected)
            {
                return "Collapsed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Visible";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public class VideoSelectedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            double selected = (double)value;
            if (selected == 0.0)
            {
                return "Collapsed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Visible";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

And this is the code that is directly maniulating the Grid named GridSelected which is defined on the  datatemplate, as if the item binded -> selected property is false the GridSelected should be Collapsed and if it is true then it should be Visible...

here is the code:

```
            ...     List<StayClassLibrary.Media> medias = await Media.GetMediasByAlbum(albmLst, App.Current.AppUser, App.Current.WSConfig);

                    if (selectedSourceZone.Count > 0)
                    {
                        selectedSourceZone.Clear();
                    }
                    selectedSourceZone = null;
                    selectedSourceZone = new ObservableCollection<IDisposable>();

                    SourceZoneSelect.ClearValue(LongListSelector.DataContextProperty);
                    SourceZoneSelect.ClearValue(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty);

                    SourceZoneSelect.UpdateLayout();
                    popupSourceZone_Select.UpdateLayout();
                    GridSourceZoneSelect.UpdateLayout();

                    if (medias.Count == 0)
                    {
                        NoImagesFound.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NoImagesFound.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

                        //TODO criar PictureItems
                        foreach (StayClassLibrary.Media item in medias)
                        {
                            BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
                            b.UriSource = new Uri(item.thumbnail, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                            b.ImageFailed += b_ImageFailed;

                            bool found = false;
                            foreach (var media in selectedContentZone)
                            {
                                if(media.GetType() == typeof(PictureItemWeb))
                                {
                                    if(((PictureItemWeb)media).idMedia == item.idMidia)
                                    {
                                        if (!selectedSourceMedias.Contains(item.idMidia.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            found = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(media.GetType() == typeof(VideoItem))
                                {
                                    if (((VideoItem)media).idMedia == item.idMidia)
                                    {
                                        if (!selectedSourceMedias.Contains(item.idMidia.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            found = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (item.type == "image")
                            {
                                selectedSourceZone.Insert(0, new PictureItemWeb
                                {
                                    Thumb = b,
                                    Pic = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
                                    dateBinary = DateTime.Now.ToBinary(),
                                    idAlbum = item.idAlbum,
                                    idMedia = item.idMidia,
                                    ImgUrl = item.source,
                                    ThumbUrl = item.thumbnail,
                                    selected = false,
                                    selectable = true,
                                    added = found,
                                    cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource()
                                });
                            }
                            else if (item.type == "video")
                            {
                                selectedSourceZone.Insert(0, new VideoItem
                                {
                                    Thumb = b,
                                    dateBinary = DateTime.Now.ToBinary(),
                                    idAlbum = item.idAlbum,
                                    idMedia = item.idMidia,
                                    VideoUrl = item.source,
                                    VideoThumbUrl = item.thumbnail,
                                    Selected = 0.0,
                                    selectable = true,
                                    added = found,
                                    cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource()
                                });
                            }
                            b = null;
                        }

                        if (selectedSourceZone.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                            DoubleAnimation fadein = new DoubleAnimation();
                            fadein.From = 0.0;
                            fadein.To = 1.0;
                            fadein.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.35));
                            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadein, SourceZoneSelect);
                            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadein, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
                            sb.Children.Add(fadein);
                            sb.Begin();

                            SourceZoneSelect.ItemsSource = null;
                            SourceZoneSelect.ClearValue(LongListSelector.DataContextProperty);
                            SourceZoneSelect.ClearValue(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty);
                            SourceZoneSelect.ItemsSource = selectedSourceZone;
// *1 

                            foreach (var item in selectedSourceZone)
                            {
                                if(item.GetType() == typeof(PictureItemWeb))
                                {
                                    if(selectedSourceMedias.Contains(((PictureItemWeb)item).idMedia.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        ((PictureItemWeb)item).selected = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(VideoItem))
                                {
                                    if (selectedSourceMedias.Contains(((VideoItem)item).idMedia.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        ((VideoItem)item).Selected = 1.0;
                                    }
                                }
                                UpdateSelectedState(SourceZoneSelect, item);    // *2
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NoImagesFound.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                            DoubleAnimation fadein = new DoubleAnimation();
                            fadein.From = 0.0;
                            fadein.To = 1.0;
                            fadein.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.35));
                            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadein, NoImagesFound);
                            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadein, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
                            sb.Children.Add(fadein);
                            sb.Begin();
                        }
                    }
```

*1 here when I set the SourceZoneSelect.ItemsSource = selectedSourceZone; it should activate the IValueConverter and it doesn't... I have a breakpoint in there and it never passes through there.

*2 this function UpdateSelectedState() I created trying to manually fix and update the GridSelected visibility for each media

```
private void UpdateSelectedState(DependencyObject targetElement, object item)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(targetElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(targetElement, i);
            if (child is Button)
            {
                Button targetItem = (Button)child;

                if (item.GetType() == typeof(PictureItemWeb))
                {
                    if (((PictureItemWeb)targetItem.DataContext).idMedia == ((PictureItemWeb)item).idMedia)
                    {
                        var g = targetItem.FindName("GridSelected");
                        if (((Guid)((Grid)g).Tag) == ((PictureItemWeb)item).idMedia)
                        {
                            if (((PictureItemWeb)item).selected)
                            {
                                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                            }
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(VideoItem))
                {
                    if (((VideoItem)targetItem.DataContext).idMedia == ((VideoItem)item).idMedia)
                    {
                        var g = targetItem.FindName("GridSelected");
                        if (((VideoItem)item).Selected == 1.0)
                        {
                            ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateSelectedState(child, item);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code when I click on an image. (All it does is change the selected property to true/false and show/hide the GridSelected for the item clicked:

```
private void Button_SourceZone_Select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var media = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
        if (media.GetType() == typeof(PictureItemWeb))
        {
            int index = selectedSourceZone.IndexOf(((PictureItemWeb)((Button)sender).DataContext));
            if (index != -1)
            {
                ((PictureItemWeb)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).selected = !((PictureItemWeb)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).selected;
            }

            var g = ((Button)sender).FindName("GridSelected");

            if (((PictureItemWeb)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).selected)
            {
                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        else if (media.GetType() == typeof(VideoItem))
        {
            int index = selectedSourceZone.IndexOf(((VideoItem)((Button)sender).DataContext));
            if (index != -1)
            {
                ((VideoItem)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).Selected = (((VideoItem)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).Selected == 0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
            }

            var g = ((Button)sender).FindName("GridSelected");

            if (((VideoItem)selectedSourceZone.ElementAt(index)).Selected == 1.0)
            {
                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Grid)g).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok all the code is here now.

The only thing that I didn't post is the fucntion when I click confirm selection.. that all it does is add the ID of the media to the list like:

```
selectedSourceMedias.Add(((PictureItemWeb)item).idMedia.ToString());
```

then it closes the popup and sets the longlistselector to null.

So when I click on a Button to show the list again. it recreates the whole list! as shown in the first code that I posted (it requests the medias, sets the longlistselector to null again and recreates the longlist Items (which PictureWeb and VideoItem are both IDisposable).

Finally! This is what is making me mad. I've debugged and everyting and it should be working perfectly!!! But here is the situation:

1. First time I onpen, all medias are unselected. thats good. (the
   ValueConverter is activated here on the first time)
2. Then if I close and open again they are recreated and still all of them are
   unselected (GridSelected are all Collapsed) (but now the
   ValueConverter is not activated)
3. Now I select the first 3 medias, the 3 UI element's GridSelected that i clicked on are changed to
   Visible, and then I confirm selection. (I debugged that the correct
   IDs were saved on the selectedSourceMedias)
4. Then I click to open the list again. (everything gets created again and right before the
   // *1 I set the ItemsSource to the newly created selectedSourceZone and the ValueConverted is not called)
5. after the // *1 I manually set the selected ones and UpdateSelectedStatus() to each one (this too on debug the correct media that was selected (first to the third) pass through the line
   ((Grid)g).Visibility =  System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
   and all the others that werent on the selectedSourceMedias ID list pass through the Collapsed line...
6. NOW when all the code runs and it returns to the emulator the 3 photos on the top (the ones that were supposed to have the GridSelected visible are Collapsed and the 3 photos ate the end of the list are shown as selected!!! (this is the bug that is driving me crazy)
7. And there is more!!! If I click on another button that load completelly new medias ( the ValueConverted is activated and all passed through the Collapsed (which is good)) the it shows the emulator and the top 3 photos are shown as selected!!!

So I think somewhere there is an internal bug that keeps data templates that have the same name ( "GridSelected" )

I know that this will probably give you a bit of a headache but.. please try to help me out!

Let me know if you had a similar problem and how You fixed it.

Thank you all in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution to my problem... If any of you find yourself with this problem... Be aware that there is a bug somewhere in the framework that doesn't clean its cache or something... the solution was for me to add these lines just before i set the SourceZoneSelect.ItemsSource :

```
SourceZoneSelect.ClearValue(LongListSelector.ItemTemplateProperty);
SourceZoneSelect.ItemTemplate = null;
SourceZoneSelect.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["DataTemplateContentZone"] as DataTemplate;
```

So if you want to run the converter everytime, you need to manually clear the template and apply it again